# Oracle daily db backup - without Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-backups

I'm a SQL Server DBA, but we have an Oracle 10g database that I need to start performing daily backups on. We do not have Enterprise Manager. Is there a way to schedule a daily backup in Oracle like in SQL Server?

I apologize if this question is severely elementary for Oracle people, but I've had a very tough time trying to research this and coming up with an answer other than "Use EM".

Comment: I guess you could take a cold backup. Read [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/21676-need-help-oracle-backup-script.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest in your case is to make a simple Windows Batch script that set ORACLE_HOME and PATH and uses rman to make the backup. Schedule the script in the Windows Task scheduler. Assuming your database is production and because of this runs in archive log mode your script could be something like this:
(I am not a Windows expert so subtle errors might be easy to spot for you)

rman_backup.bat:

```
ORACLE_SID=your_oracle_sid
ORACLE_HOME=d:/where/your/installation/is
PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
rman cmdfile=your_rman_actions_script.rman log=your_log_file.log
```

your_rman_action_script.rman looks like

```
connect target=/
backup DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
```

For documentation look at [Oracle 10g database documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage) and start with 2 day dba. After that check out the backup docu found here [Administration](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/portal.portal_db?selected=4)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks for the solution and the awesome Oracle doc links. So, are there no scheduled jobs in Oracle like there are in SQL Server?

Comment: There are scheduled jobs but 10g is a bit old. I don't like to use the old 10g external jobs for backup. In 11g this is a different case.

Answer (score 0):

I would (but then, my background is more on Unix, less on Windows) do the scheduling from outside the database, using the OS Scheduler to run a backup script. Assuming that no real backup system is available.

In the beginning of backup, you would run a SQL script to place the tablespaces in backup mode (ALTER TABLESPACE x BEGIN BACKUP), then back up the tablespace data files, and after that restore normal mode (ALTER TABLESPACE x END BACKUP). PL/SQL can be used here for looping over all tablespaces.

After that, you'd back up the control file (ALTER SYSTEM BACKUP CONTROLFILE ...), and finally you would rotate the redo logs enough times that all relevant log data has been archived, and back up the archive logs.

And as of doing incremental backups f.ex. throughout the working week, just do the log rotation & archive log copy part.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a scheduled sort of task, and if possible, I'd like to do this from within SQL Developer. I'm running Windows 7 and the server is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: As I wrote, with this you'd use an external scheduling mechanism, f.ex. something provided by the operating system (Unix-like systems have cron; I assume there's some general-purpose scheduling thing available on Windows platforms as well).